# Under which conditions the following infinite integral involving a zeroth order Bessel function is convergent / defined?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals, bessel-functions

Everybody hello,

The goal is to determine the non-trivial conditions between the real parameters $a$, $b$, and $c$, for which infinite integral below is convergent / defined:
$$
\int_0^\infty q J_0(qr) \big( q(a+b\cos q) + c \sin q\big)  \, \mathrm{d}q \, ,
$$
where $0 \le r \le 1$.

My search through the literature has brought me the following relations which might be of use:

$$
\int_0^\infty J_0(qr)\cos(q) \, \mathrm{d}q = \frac{H(r-1)}{(r^2-1)^{1/2}} \, , \\
\int_0^\infty J_0(qr)\sin(q) \, \mathrm{d}q = \frac{H(1-r)}{(1-r^2)^{1/2}} \, ,
$$
where $H$ denotes the Heaviside step function.

Any hints or suggestions are most welcome. Thank you!